# Try to upload file from lambda tmp folder to s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to lambda function and I am trying to upload file to s3 bucket from lambda function.
creating multiple zip file to tmp folder and after that I want to upload that zip file to s3 bucket, I have given permission to access s3 bucket to lambda function its not showing any error
I tried different approach to resolve this but not able to fixed it.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import delay from "delay";
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: "***",
    secretAccessKey: "***",
    region: "***"
});


const uploadFullfile = () =>{
// reg ex to match
var re = /\.zip$/;

// ensure that this file is in the directory of the files you want to run the cronjob on
fs.readdir("/tmp/",function(err: any, files: any) {
    if (err) {
        console.log( "Could not list the directory.", err);
        process.exit( 1 )
    }

    var matches = files.filter( function(text: any) { return re.test(text) } )
    var numFiles = matches.length;
    if ( numFiles ) {
        // Read in the file, convert it to base64, store to S3

        for(let i = 0; i < numFiles; i++ ) {
            uploadCandidate(matches[i])
        }

    }

})


const uploadCandidate = (fileName:any) => {
  fs.readFile('/tmp/'+fileName, async(err:any, data:any) => {
     console.log("entry",fileName);
     if (err) throw err;
     
     console.log("params")
    await s3.putObject({
         Bucket: 'testbucket', // pass your bucket name
         Key: fileName, // file will be saved as testBucket/contacts.csv
         ContentType: 'application/zip',
         Body: data,
      },function (resp) {
        console.log('Done');
      });
  //delay(1000);
  //fs.unlink('/tmp/'+fileName, function(){
  //    console.log("deleting file");
  //  console.log('/tmp/'+fileName);
  //});
 
    
});
}
 
}

export default uploadFullfile;
```

I am not getting any error and I have give permission to access s3 bucket
output I am getting

```
2021-01-14T17:22:38.354+05:30   2021-01-14T11:52:38.354Z *** INFO entry state_fullfile_2021-01-14-11:01:03_part0.zip

2021-01-14T17:22:38.354+05:30   2021-01-14T11:52:38.354Z *** INFO params

2021-01-14T17:22:38.375+05:30   2021-01-14T11:52:38.374Z *** INFO entry association_fullfile_2021-01-14-11:01:03_part5.zip

2021-01-14T17:22:38.375+05:30   2021-01-14T11:52:38.375Z *** INFO params

2021-01-14T17:22:38.378+05:30   2021-01-14T11:52:38.378Z *** INFO entry remark_table_fullfile_2021-01-14-11:01:03_part1.zip

2021-01-14T17:22:38.378+05:30   2021-01-14T11:52:38.378Z **** INFO params

2021-01-14T17:22:38.394+05:30   END RequestId: ****

2021-01-14T17:22:38.394+05:30   REPORT RequestId: *** Duration: 83.91 ms Billed Duration: 84 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 322 MB
```

Comment: Since you are using `async` are you sure you are properly awaiting for all the results?

Comment: yes waiting for all result but not working

Comment: The question is not clear about the event handler of the lambda function. What is the lambda trigger?

Comment: Event handler of lambda is  calling uploadFullfile() I have written in other file that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem occurs due to permission issue of VPC endpoint. Here is the solution

[new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/)

Answer (score 0):

did you tried increasing the lambda function time and tried?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)